# SQL query to create a new table with existing data manipulation and operation with group by and aggegate function

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like below.

```
month   year    country test    affected    cases
4   2020    A   5   2   4
4   2020    A   57  10  20
4   2020    A   6   3   5
3   2020    A   9   5   7
3   2020    A   0   0   0
3   2020    A   6   2   4
1   2019    A   4   1   3
1   2019    A   2   1   1
4   2020    B   5   2   4
4   2020    B   57  10  20
4   2020    B   6   3   5
3   2020    B   9   5   7
3   2020    B   0   0   0
4   2019    C   6   3   5
1   2019    C   4   1   3
```

Then i have to do the following operation

[image]

And finally i want to get the below output.

[image]

That means i have to sum all the test values in month like 4 . 4 means april. and show the 4 as April and so on.

How can i achieve this?

I have tried with this below. But No Sucess.

```
     SELECT month, year ,sum(cases/Tests*100%) as caseRate, sum(affected/cases * 100%) as affectedrate ,country FROM csv group by country ,month ,year")
```

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The title describes what you have to do - do you have a specific problem?

Comment: As i am newbie and the problem looks harder to me. i need the way out to solve this

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions also I love that you profiles lists experience in 3 (cone em) sql dialects

Comment: @scaisEdge i have tried with this but no luck.    SELECT month, year ,sum(cases/Tests*100%) as caseRate, sum(affected/cases * 100%) as affectedrate ,country FROM csv group by country ,month ,year")

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just an aggregation query:

```
select month, year, country,
      sum(cases) * 100 / sum(test) as case_rate,
      sum(affected) * 100 / sum(cases) as affected_rate
from t
group by month, year, country;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way

```
    SELECT month
        ,  monthname(str_to_date(MonthNum,'%m')) Monthname
        , year 
        ,country 
        , sum((cases)/sum(Tests))*100 as caseRate
        , sum((affected)/sum(cases))*100 as affectedrate 
    FROM csv
    group by country ,month , Monthname, year
```

Comment: i have to show 4 as Month Name April. or 3 as March. How can it possible

Comment: @MahmudRiad  answer  updated ..   with month name